# Infinite POST request on uploading file with Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-file-upload

I try to upload some files to a server through a web interface with Django.

**HTML :**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_file">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file_list" multiple>
    <button class="rounded-full bg-violet-200 text-violet-700 block p-2" name="upload_file" value="dummy" type="submit">Ajouter des fichiers</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def media_manager(request):
    file_manager = MediaManager.server.FileManager(django.conf.settings.USER_FILE_ROOT)

    # POST utilisé pour associer les tags aux images
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get("upload_file"):
            for uploaded_file in request.FILES.getlist("uploaded_file_list"):
                file_manager.add_file(uploaded_file)

    context_dict = {}
    context_dict["filtered_file_list"]  = MediaManager.filters.ImageFilter(request.GET, queryset=MediaManager.models.UserImage.objects.all())

    return django.shortcuts.render(request, "MediaManager/media_manager.html", context=context_dict)
```

**FileManager.py**

```
def add_file(self, uploaded_file):
    file_system_storage = django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage(location=self._user_dir_absolute_path)
    file_system_storage.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
```

**FileManager also updates context_dict["filtered_dile_list"] with the files uploaded.**

When I upload a file on the browser, the file is correctly uploaded and the web display also correctly add it on the page. I can see the upload POST request.
**But this operation is repeated infinitely.**

Here is the log (with a request.POST print) :

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['vCHAoeGg3QVIZDuHAls8lmV7Y8MXHqxGeWQj16N2zJcCUfoML4pVcnsmJGk7R5Er'], 'upload_file': ['dummy']}>
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:23] "POST /media_manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19214

1 static file copied to '/home/gautitho/workspace/MonPetitNuage/MonPetitNuage/static', 185 unmodified.

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['vCHAoeGg3QVIZDuHAls8lmV7Y8MXHqxGeWQj16N2zJcCUfoML4pVcnsmJGk7R5Er'], 'upload_file': ['dummy']}>
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:24] "POST /media_manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19580
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:24] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 63919

1 static file copied to '/home/gautitho/workspace/MonPetitNuage/MonPetitNuage/static', 186 unmodified.

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['vCHAoeGg3QVIZDuHAls8lmV7Y8MXHqxGeWQj16N2zJcCUfoML4pVcnsmJGk7R5Er'], 'upload_file': ['dummy']}>
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:25] "POST /media_manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19959
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:25] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:25] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch_tuThoGu.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 63919

1 static file copied to '/home/gautitho/workspace/MonPetitNuage/MonPetitNuage/static', 187 unmodified.

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['vCHAoeGg3QVIZDuHAls8lmV7Y8MXHqxGeWQj16N2zJcCUfoML4pVcnsmJGk7R5Er'], 'upload_file': ['dummy']}>
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:26] "POST /media_manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20338
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:26] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch_tuThoGu.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:26] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Nov/2022 22:03:26] "GET /static/MediaManager/user/Couleurs-logo-Overwatch_2i1PCzd.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 63919
```

Comment: `return django.shortcuts.render(request, "MediaManager/media_manager.html", context=context_dict)` Does that render call point back to the same view?

Comment: Yes, it calls the same view.

Comment: Then that's the problem.  The view does its work, then returns a redirect to itself, which does the work again and redirects to itself again, over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs:

> you should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good web development practice in general.

So the view should be like this:

```py
def media_manager(request):
    file_manager = MediaManager.server.FileManager(django.conf.settings.USER_FILE_ROOT)

    # POST utilisé pour associer les tags aux images
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get("upload_file"):
            for uploaded_file in request.FILES.getlist("uploaded_file_list"):
                file_manager.add_file(uploaded_file)
            return redirect("success")

    context_dict = {}
    context_dict["filtered_file_list"]  = MediaManager.filters.ImageFilter(request.GET, queryset=MediaManager.models.UserImage.objects.all())
   

    return django.shortcuts.render(request, "MediaManager/media_manager.html", context=context_dict)


def success(request):
    return django.shortcuts.render(request, "MediaManager/file_success.html")
```

Also don't need to give same name in form tag itself as given in button which is `upload_file` remove that.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns=[
    #...
    path("file_success/",views.success,name="success")
]
    #...
```

file_success.html:

```html
<body>
    <h2>The file has been uploaded successfully. </h2>
    <a href="{% url 'your_media_manager_view_name' %}"> uplad page </a> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
Does I have this behavior because the request object given to render still have the POST request in it ?

Comment: @Gautitho You had this behaviour of infinite redirecting since whenever the POST request was made, it do all Operations of adding file from file list or whatever it had to do but the moment control came out from if condition, it rendered the same template again with the context you given for GET request resulting in infinite calling of same template irrespective of the request method. Currently, Whenever the data is coming from POST it redirects it to success page so if request's method is POST it will redirect and if GET then it will render template with context.